# VWO Asynchronous Smartcode Not Connecting for AB Test

Tags: asynchronous, aem, vwo

We are trying to implement an AB test using [VWO Asynch Smartcode](https://help.vwo.com/hc/en-us/articles/360019420774-What-is-VWO-SmartCode-) to track form submissions on our website. Website is hosted in AEM and we have included the script (see below) directly into our head.html file.

VWO support has said that the tracking is failing because the initiator of this file needs to be our index file, not the individual pages.

```js
<!-- Start VWO Async SmartCode -->
<link rel="preconnect" href="https://dev.visualwebsiteoptimizer.com" />
<script type='text/javascript' id='vwoCode'>
window._vwo_code=window._vwo_code || (function() {
var account_id=XXXXX,
version = 1.5,
settings_tolerance=2000,
library_tolerance=2500,
use_existing_jquery=false,
is_spa=1,
hide_element='body',
hide_element_style = 'opacity:0 !important;filter:alpha(opacity=0) !important;background:none !important',
/* DO NOT EDIT BELOW THIS LINE */
f=false,w=window,d=document,vwoCodeEl=d.querySelector('#vwoCode'),code={use_existing_jquery:function(){return use_existing_jquery},library_tolerance:function(){return library_tolerance},hide_element_style:function(){return'{'+hide_element_style+'}'},finish:function(){if(!f){f=true;var e=d.getElementById('_vis_opt_path_hides');if(e)e.parentNode.removeChild(e)}},finished:function(){return f},load:function(e){var t=d.createElement('script');t.fetchPriority='high';t.src=e;t.type='text/javascript';t.onerror=function(){_vwo_code.finish()};d.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(t)},getVersion:function(){return version},getMatchedCookies:function(e){var t=[];if(document.cookie){t=document.cookie.match(e)||[]}return t},getCombinationCookie:function(){var e=code.getMatchedCookies(/(?:^|;)\s?(_vis_opt_exp_\d+_combi=[^;$]*)/gi);e=e.map(function(e){try{var t=decodeURIComponent(e);if(!/_vis_opt_exp_\d+_combi=(?:\d+,?)+\s*$/.test(t)){return''}return t}catch(e){return''}});var i=[];e.forEach(function(e){var t=e.match(/([\d,]+)/g);t&&i.push(t.join('-'))});return i.join('|')},init:function(){if(d.URL.indexOf('__vwo_disable__')>-1)return;w.settings_timer=setTimeout(function(){_vwo_code.finish()},settings_tolerance);var e=d.currentScript,t=d.createElement('style'),i=e&&!e.async?hide_element?hide_element+'{'+hide_element_style+'}':'':code.lA=1,n=d.getElementsByTagName('head')[0];t.setAttribute('id','_vis_opt_path_hides');vwoCodeEl&&t.setAttribute('nonce',vwoCodeEl.nonce);t.setAttribute('type','text/css');if(t.styleSheet)t.styleSheet.cssText=i;else t.appendChild(d.createTextNode(i));n.appendChild(t);var o=this.getCombinationCookie();this.load('https://dev.visualwebsiteoptimizer.com/j.php?a='+account_id+'&u='+encodeURIComponent(d.URL)+'&f='+ +is_spa+'&vn='+version+(o?'&c='+o:''));return settings_timer}};w._vwo_settings_timer = code.init();return code;}());
</script>
<!-- End VWO Async SmartCode -->
```

I have read most all of the VWO documentation, had a meeting with the support team and am still not able to get this working. Any ideas appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

This is Aditi, Manager - VWO Support.

I checked the past tickets and noticed that Toufik confirmed that metric is tracking the conversions correctly. Having said this, if the SmartCode is placed via the head.html file, it should not affect the tracking of the conversions.

Thus, could you please share the campaign details (name or id) once so that we can then check the setup for the respective campaign and assist further.

Thanks
Aditi

Comment: Thanks for the follow up. We are trying to setup a meeting with support now, so I'll save the details for then.